# following query is slow because of the subquery used in column list?

Tags: php, mysql

While working on one of my project I am facing problem of slow query.

```
(
SELECT
  mem.mem_id,
  mem.photo,
  mem.fname,
  mem.lname,
  mem.email,
  mem.profilenam,
  mem.birthday,
  mem.phone,
  mem.sn_flag,
  (SELECT
     stat
   FROM invite
   WHERE email = mem.email
       AND mem_id = 48) AS stat,
  (SELECT
     inv_id
   FROM invite
   WHERE email = mem.email
       AND mem_id = 48) AS invid
FROM `future_members` AS mem
  JOIN `network` AS tmem
    ON (mem.mem_id = tmem.frd_id)
WHERE tmem.mem_id = 48
    AND mem.verified = 'y'
    AND mem.deleted = 'N'
    AND profile_type != 'C'
    AND mem.updated_by = 48
) 
UNION 
(SELECT
  tnmem.id,
  mem.photo,
  tnmem.name,
  tnmem.lname,
  tnmem.email,
  tnmem.profilenm,
  tnmem.birthday,
  tnmem.phone,
  tnmem.sn_flag,
  (SELECT
     stat
   FROM invite
   WHERE email = tnmem.email
       AND mem_id = 48) AS stat,
  (SELECT
     inv_id
   FROM invite
   WHERE email = tnmem.email
       AND mem_id = 48) AS invid
FROM `future_members` AS tnmem
  JOIN `members` AS mem
    ON (mem.mem_id = tnmem.addedby)
WHERE tnmem.addedby = 48 
) 
ORDER BY TRIM(lname) ASC LIMIT 0, 20
```

This is the query which is taking around 10-12 seconds each time when page loads
.I have found that this particular portion is repeated in each select tag column list

```
(SELECT
     stat
   FROM invite
   WHERE email = mem.email
       AND mem_id = 48)
```

I had separated each query and optimized and individual query was performing fast. but when added that in main query the result was different .

Please suggest any solution for optimizing above main query...

this is what I get when I use EXPLAIN keyword in query

```
table       type    possible_keys           key key_len ref                 rows    Extra
mem     ALL (NULL)              (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)                  12622   Using where
tmem        ref mem_id,frd_id,mem_id_3,mem_id_2 frd_id  8   database.mem.mem_id         1   Using where
invite      ALL (NULL)              (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)                  640 Using where
invite      ALL (NULL)              (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)                  640 Using where
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is specifically the `invite` subquery, then add an index on `invite(email, mem_id, stat)`.  That should improve the performance.

Overall, you can improve the performance of this query in a variety of ways:

- Is the `union` necessary?  Can it be replaced with a `union all`?
- Instead of calculating the subquery values before the union, do this work *after* the `limit`, so you are calling the subquery fewer times.
- Indexes can probably help in other places as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply .. as you said to add index on invite table .It is feasible to add index on mem_id and email but is there is requirement to add index on stat column too

Comment: @veronicafernadis . . . You want a composite index with multiple columns -- not multiple indexes.  The stated index "covers" the subquery, so the index can entirely resolve the query and there is no need to go to the data pages for the table.  That is why I included all three columns.